# Module not found error while running python program via command prompt

Tags: python, git-bash

I am running the unit tests via runtests.sh file on git bash shell as `$ sh runtests.sh`. here's how my directory structure looks like.

```
|- project
|   |-- transformations
|       |-- udf_functions
|           |-- udf_serviceA
|               |-- function1.py
|               |-- function2.py
|- unittests
|   |-- tests_for_serviceA
|        |-- unit_tests.py
|- requirements.txt
|- install_requirements.cmd
|- runtests.sh
```

And my `runtests.sh` contents are:

```
python unittests/tests_for_serviceA/unit_tests.py
py.test --cov=. --cov-branch --cov-report=html --junitxml=test_results.xml test "$@"
coverage xml
```

When I run this file on GitBash command line it does imports all the other inbuilt modules in python but not the ones that I have written. For example, it throws an error that `module function1 not found`. In script, I am importing function as `from transformations.udf_functions.udf_serviceA import function1`

Is there anything wrong with my directory placement? If not then what is causing this error.

Comment: are you using virtual environment?

Comment: no i am running this via gitbash on windows

Answer (score 0):

Add the utility path in the pytest.ini configuration file like below:-

```
[pytest]
python_paths = . <path of utility>
```